# API Rails : How to make a RESTFul API using Devise & JWT?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, devise, jwt, devise-jwt

I'm trying to build a RESTFul API with devise & jwt.

I can register, and login/logout using my jwt bear token, using Postman.

Now I have a problem when I want to POST an Article.

I dont understand why my console goes for a login after I POST an Article with Postman.

Also I dont understand why I get this 401 error. It's really hard to find some content with RESTFul + API + Devise + JWT.

Do you think it's better in the long term to run with or without Devise ? Cause there is actually some content without Devise.

**What I try on Postman**

```
Authorization : <Bearer token>
 { 
    "title":"the title",
    "content":"the content"
 }
```

**Returned ERROR message** from the console when I post an Article with Postman ( and with a the same bear token as for login/logout

```
Started POST "/articles" for ::1 at 2021-09-01 18:07:41 +0200
Processing by ArticlesController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"title"=>"the title", "content"=>"the content", "article"=>{"title"=>"the title", "content"=>"the content"}}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 76ms (Allocations: 113)


Started GET "/api/login" for ::1 at 2021-09-01 18:07:41 +0200
Processing by SessionsController#new as JSON
Completed 200 OK in 71ms (Views: 2.5ms | Allocations: 179)
```

**app/controllers/articles_controller.rb**

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_todo, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
 before_action :authenticate_user!

 # GET /todos
 def index
   @articles = Article.all
   json_response(@articles)
 end

 # POST /todos
 def create
   @article = Article.create!(article_params)
   @article.user = current_user

 end

 # GET /todos/:id
 def show
   json_response(@article)
 end

 # PUT /todos/:id
 def update
   @article.update(article_params)
   head :no_content
 end

 # DELETE /todos/:id
 def destroy
   @article.destroy
   head :no_content
 end

 private

 def article_params
   # whitelist params
   params.permit(:title, :content, :user_id)
 end

 def set_article
   @article = Article.find(params[:id])
 end
end
```

**db/shema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_09_01_124211) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_articles_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "jwt_denylist", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "jti", null: false
    t.datetime "expired_at", null: false
    t.index ["jti"], name: "index_jwt_denylist_on_jti"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "articles", "users"
end
```

**app/models/article.rb**

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user
end
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
  :jwt_authenticatable, jwt_revocation_strategy: JwtDenylist

  has_many :articles
end
```

Comment: "Do you think it's better in the long term to run with or without Devise?". It depends on if you actually need the functionality that devise provides in terms of views and controllers for stuff like user sign ups. There are other alternative which are more light weight weight like Knock for pure API applications.

Comment: Also instead of postman write an actual integration test (request spec) which is a far better methodology as its repeatable by others and guards against regressions. Here the result could be messed up by how the token made its way via you into postman.